# Checkbox value in React and MongoDB

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

What I am seeking to accomplish is to have an optional checkbox in a form that returns false when unchecked and true when checked (in the DB). 
However, whenever I view my submission in the console, things appear to be find - just not showing up in Mongo. I have attempted numerous things after searching all day both frontend and backend schema. Any help or insight would be much appreciated.

```
    export default class CreateworkOrder extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onChangeEmployee = this.onChangeEmployee.bind(this);
    this.onChangeDescription = this.onChangeDescription.bind(this);
    this.onChangeDuration = this.onChangeDuration.bind(this);
    this.onChangeDate = this.onChangeDate.bind(this);
    this.handleCheckClick = this.handleCheckClick.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      employee: '',
      description: '',
      duration: 0,
      date: new Date(),
      employees: [],
      isComplete: false
    }

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/employees/')
      .then(response => {
        if (response.data.length > 0) {
          this.setState({
            employees: response.data.map(emp => emp.employee),
            employee: response.data[0].employee
          })
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })

  }

  handleCheckClick = () => {
      const complete = !this.state.isComplete;
      console.log(complete);
      this.setState({ complete: !this.state.isComplete});
}
```

> Then submit below:

```
onSubmit(e) {
e.preventDefault();

const workOrder = {
  employee: this.state.employee,
  description: this.state.description,
  duration: this.state.duration,
  date: this.state.date,
  isComplete: this.state.isComplete
}

console.log(workOrder);

 axios.post('http://localhost:5000/workOrders/add', workOrder)
  .then(res => console.log(res.data)).catch(console.error);
  //window.location = '/home';
```

}

> portion of the form to optionally select

```
        <div className="form-group">
      <label>Only check box if job has been completed   </label>
    <input name="isComplete" type="checkbox" 
    defaultChecked={this.state.isComplete} 
    onChange={this.handleCheckClick} 
    className="filled-in" id="filled-in-box"/>
  </div>


    <div className="form-group">
      <input type="submit" value="Create WO" className="btn btn-primary" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}/>
    </div>
  </form>
```

> DB Model

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const workorderSchema = new Schema({
  employee: { type: String, required: true },
  description: { type: String, required: true },
  duration: { type: Number, required: true },
  date: { type: Date, required: true },
  isComplete: { type: Boolean, required: false },
}, 
{
  timestamps: true,
});

const WorkOrder = mongoose.model('WorkOrder', workorderSchema);

module.exports = WorkOrder;
```

[image: isComplete not passsed after submit]

but console does show true

[image: console]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the state variable `isComplete` but setting the state in `complete`.

> this.state = {
>         employee: '',
>         description: '',
>         duration: 0,
>         date: new Date(),
>         employees: [],
>         **isComplete: false**
>       }

In handleCheckClick you are doing:

> handleCheckClick = () => {
>         const complete = !this.state.isComplete;
>         console.log(complete);
>         this.setState({ **complete: !this.state.isComplete**}); }

And you are submitting `workOrder` which is using `isComplete`, which you didn't change

> const workOrder = {   employee: this.state.employee,   description:
>   this.state.description,   duration: this.state.duration,   date:
>   this.state.date,   **isComplete: this.state.isComplete** }

This should be the reason. So change the handleCheckClick like this:

```
handleCheckClick = () => {
      let complete = !this.state.isComplete;
      console.log(complete);
      this.setState({ isComplete: complete});
}
```

Also, I noticed that you are using `const` keyword and then trying to change its value. `const` means the value shouldn't change. Use either `let` or `var` in future if you want  a variable to be mutable

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I made the changes and unfortunately still no luck. I added two screenshots in my post above (bottom).

Comment: Disregard - had an issue with my route/backend*
Thx